# change one cell in gridView

Tags: java, android, gridview

How can I add a int value to just one cell in a gridView? for example, using only the first  cells and assigning them a value . Is there a way to do that?

This is my grid in the xml:

```
    <GridView
            android:id="@+id/grid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:numColumns="3" >
        </GridView>
```

this is my java:

```
    int first = 5;
    int second = 6
    GridView grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
    //I'm missing here a line something like: grid.setContentOfCell (1, first); grid.setContentOfCell (2, second)
```

I want to assign the int A to the first cell in the grid and B to the second.

Comment: can you show your code? Do you use a Custom Adapter? How do you populate gridview. not enough code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GridView getView Method Check the position is grater than 4 and also put other Cell value according to postion value that you want.

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {

    if(position>3)
    {

   productPriceTextView.setText("1-4")

     }else if(position==a)

    Display your value

   }else if(position==b)

    Display your value

    }
```

Thanks

Comment: @MdAbdulGafur have you considered views recycling also?

Comment: no, I just Put value according to condition, here is not all code , just sample code.

Comment: can you add some code instead of "display your value"? I don't know the method to display the value.

Comment: are you use BaseAdapter to create GridView?

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/ and read about android GridView and BaseAdapter that help to this work..

Comment: @עמוסרום why gridview cannot work with adapter. totally wrong. also on what condition/event you want to change the textview?

Comment: on click of a button that I didn't show here the code to. Why does it matter?

Comment: @עמוסרום it does matter i will show why it matters in a while

Comment: @MdAbdulGafur you have not considered gridview recycling views which will cause problem. don't think this is correct

Comment: @עמוסרום ok if you think this works go ahead and implement it. No problem. I just wanted to point at something. One suggestion have more items than what you see on screen try scrolling gridview and see what happens. Just my curiosity